# Xcode word completion shortcut

Tags: macos, xcode, auto-complete, keybindings

Xcode's code autocompletion is quite good, I am missing one thing though:
in vim I can press ctrl+n to autocomplete any word, even those in the comment.

Here is a screenshot from xcode to show what I mean:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to achieve I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`Control–Space bar` is used to either turn the Auto-Complete ON/OFF. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CompletingCode/CompletingCode.html)

Comment: this does not answer the question at all. The question is not how to turn Auto-Complete on or off, but how to autocomplete regular words as opposed to symbols the compiler recognizes.

Comment: The answer is actually correct, only language is ambiguous. By turning on/off means showing and hiding the suggestion box. Give it a try.

Comment: I gave it a try and I can confirm: The answer is NOT correct. It is NOT doing the simple word completion any way. Exactly as shown by the screenshot in the original question...